# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1426, "Too big precision 200 specified for 'price'. Maximum is 65.")

Tags: django

I am trying to DecimalField I set the parameter max_digits to 200,

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=200, decimal_places=2)
```

It showed the error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1426, "Too big precision 200
>   specified for 'price'. Maximum is 65.")

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65, decimal_places=2)
```

So I changed it to 65, but it still it shows the same error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1426, "Too big precision 200
>   specified for 'price'. Maximum is 65.")

Comment: you just changed the column in your model, but the original column still remains in DB as it was before (200), so you have to create & apply DB migration.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I run python manage.py makemigrations it showed "No changes detected"

Comment: Then Django probably doesnt generate migration for this kind of change automatically. Point remains - your column in DB is already created as 200. Either change it manually via `ALTER`, write the migration manually, or drop DB & create it again. Whatever feels most convenient to you.

Answer (score 3):

After doing corrections in the model field

- Delete the 'migrations' folder under '*your_app_name*'
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name` 
  new table should have been created
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

it worked for me with MySql , in Django 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

**After searching over the internet I did the following steps and it worked.**

1. Delete your pycache from your app_name and also from inner project_name.
2. Run command python manage.py makemigrations
3. then run, python manage.py migrate**